# perl regex too greedy

Tags: perl, regex-greedy, fix-protocol

I went through similar questions asked by other members and applied (or tried to apply) solutions from their inquiry but they did not work on my issue.  My pattern match and grouping is too greedy and does not stop at first pipe(|).  If I get more specific, I think it can but I'm trying to figure out how I can stop the pattern match at the first instance of the pipe?

Here are couple of lines

```
09:30:00.063|IN:|8=FIX.4.2|9=206|35=D|34=5159|49=CLIENT|52=20191024-13:30:00.050|56=SERV|57=DEST|1=05033|11=ABZ5702|15=USD|21=1|38=2000|40=2|44=92.48|47=A|54=5|55=RC|60=20191024-13:30:00.050|111=0|114=N|336=X|5700=AP|9281=SOV|10=202
09:37:21.208|IN:|8=FIX.4.2|9=170|35=D|34=5184|49=CLIENT|52=20191024-13:37:21.206|56=SERV|57=ATXB|1=J5129|11=136404|15=USD|21=1|38=100|40=2|44=1.39|47=A|54=2|55=DIW|59=2|60=20191024-13:30:00.206|10=029
```

I'm expecting my perl script to return the following output from the above data:

```
09:30:00.063|13:30:00.050|ABZ5702
09:37:21.208|13:37:21.206|136404
```

I tried all this and few other veriations but could not get it to produce the above output:

````
    #$msg =~ s/([^|]*).*|52=([^|]*).*|11=([^|]*).*/$1|$2|$3/;
    $msg =~ s/(.+)\|??.*|52=([^|]*).*|11=([^|]*).*/$1|$2|$3/;
    #$msg =~ s/^([^|]*).??|52=([^|]*).??|11=([^|]*).*/$1|$2|$3/;
    #$msg =~ s/^([^\|??]*).*|52=([^\|??]*).*|11=([^\|??]*).*/$1|$2|$3/;
    #$msg =~ s/(.*\|??).*|52=(.+\|??).*|11=(.+\|??).*/one $1|two $2|three $3/;
    #$msg =~ s/(.*?|).*|52=(.*?|).*|11=(.*|?).*/$1|$2|$3/;
    #$msg =~ /(.*)|??.*|52=(.*)|??.*|11=(.*)|??.*/$1|$2|$3/;
    #$msg =~ s/|.*-[0-3][0-9]:/|/;

print "$msg\n";```
````

I realize there are other more than one way to skin the cat but there are cases where I need to use the pattern match approach.  How can I get it to produce the expected output using the pattern matching where it stops each group at first pipe(|)? Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
`s/(.*?)\|.*\|52=([^|]*).*\|11=([^|]*).*/$1 $2 $3/;`

There were a couple of pipe delimiters that needed escaping.

You need to look at non-greedy matching https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch06_16.htm

The first matching group is `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)`. The `?` means we match as little as possible.

In general, for parsing FIX in perl, as long as there are no repeating groups, I would recommend splitting on `|` first and then creating a hash of tag-value pairs.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick!

I could have swore I tried something very similar.  Maybe I used "?" in all groups.
I think I understand your suggestion to create a hash from the FIX msgs but I only care about the two timestamps and tag 11. What I'm doing is comparing the two timestamps and if the first one is greater than certain threshold, send out an alert with the two time stamps along with tag 11.  My concern with hash is that what if the data set changes? I wouldn't be able to compare the two hashes b/c the two timestamps could end up in a different location.

Comment: Why do we need to make it less greedy on the first group (.*?) and not the rest of the groups(*)?

Comment: It's because you're using [^|]*, which is telling it to match as many non-'|' characters as possible. But it can only do this up to the next '|' so you don't see any greedy behaviour there.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it a little bit different - split line into array and work on individual element of array.

The regex may be an acceptable solution for one particular case if format of line predetermined and will never change.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    my @array = split /\|/, $line;

    print Dumper(\@array) if $debug;

    $array[7]  =~ s/.+?-//;
    $array[11] =~ s/\d+=//;

    printf "%s\n", join '|', @array[0,7,11];

}

__DATA__
09:30:00.063|IN:|8=FIX.4.2|9=206|35=D|34=5159|49=CLIENT|52=20191024-13:30:00.050|56=SERV|57=DEST|1=05033|11=ABZ5702|15=USD|21=1|38=2000|40=2|44=92.48|47=A|54=5|55=RC|60=20191024-13:30:00.050|111=0|114=N|336=X|5700=AP|9281=SOV|10=202
09:37:21.208|IN:|8=FIX.4.2|9=170|35=D|34=5184|49=CLIENT|52=20191024-13:37:21.206|56=SERV|57=ATXB|1=J5129|11=136404|15=USD|21=1|38=100|40=2|44=1.39|47=A|54=2|55=DIW|59=2|60=20191024-13:30:00.206|10=029
```

Comment: If you would specify name of each field then **hash** would be more appropriate than array -- it would be easier to work with **key=value** pair. In case of **array** I had **to count** what **element of array** I need to address to change it.

Comment: Parsing first (e.g. using `split`) is definitely a better approach.

Comment: Tip: You could use `say` (with `use feature qw( say );` or `use 5.010;`) or `CORE::say` (without) instead of `printf "%s\n", `

Comment: Is there any problem with **printf**? Due which it is undesirable to use it? There are many ways to output information. Still thanks for _Tip_.

Comment: No, `say` is simply simpler then `printf "%s\n",`. That's why it's a tip and not a bug fix :) (`printf $s` would be bad since it could result in garbled output, but that's something else.)